# contao news detail page url generation issue

Tags: content-management-system, contao

Hi I have a multi domain site. I have some news archives .I configured redirect page to a news detail page in my first domain. In my second domain I used the same news archive. Created a news list page and news detail page. In newslist module of second domain , I need different detail page. So i installed newslist_extended extension. There is an option to select different detail page.
   In my first domain, the news list and detail is properly displayed. But in my second domain, whem I am clicking on a news item it goes to 404 page. 
   The url generated is http://myDomain/news/news-item.html . When I search 
http://myDomain/news/news-detail/news-item.html  , the news is displayed. How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Without knowing more about your setup we cannot tell you how to 'fix' this.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually a problem in the `newslist_extended` extension, which is now fixed in version `1.1.3`: https://github.com/fritzmg/contao-newslist-extended/issues/1